Hi all, I'm having some doubts about a piece of code in the GnosisSafe contract and I hope I can get an answer!
function checkNSignatures(
    bytes32 dataHash,
    bytes memory data,
    bytes memory signatures,
    uint256 requiredSignatures
) public view {
    // Check that the provided signature data is not too short
    require(signatures.length >= requiredSignatures.mul(65), "GS020");
    // There cannot be an owner with address 0.
    address lastOwner = address(0);
    address currentOwner;
    uint8 v;
    bytes32 r;
    bytes32 s;
    uint256 i;
    for (i = 0; i < requiredSignatures; i++) {
        (v, r, s) = signatureSplit(signatures, i);
        if (v == 0) {
            // If v is 0 then it is a contract signature
            // When handling contract signatures the address of the contract is encoded into r
            currentOwner = address(uint160(uint256(r)));

            // Check that signature data pointer (s) is not pointing inside the static part of the signatures bytes
            // This check is not completely accurate, since it is possible that more signatures than the threshold are send.
            // Here we only check that the pointer is not pointing inside the part that is being processed
            require(uint256(s) >= requiredSignatures.mul(65), "GS021");

            // Check that signature data pointer (s) is in bounds (points to the length of data -> 32 bytes)
            require(uint256(s).add(32) <= signatures.length, "GS022");

            // Check if the contract signature is in bounds: start of data is s + 32 and end is start + signature length
            uint256 contractSignatureLen;
            // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
            assembly {
                contractSignatureLen := mload(add(add(signatures, s), 0x20))
            }
            require(uint256(s).add(32).add(contractSignatureLen) <= signatures.length, "GS023");

            // Check signature
            bytes memory contractSignature;
            // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
            assembly {
                // The signature data for contract signatures is appended to the concatenated signatures and the offset is stored in s
                contractSignature := add(add(signatures, s), 0x20)
            }
            require(ISignatureValidator(currentOwner).isValidSignature(data, contractSignature) == EIP1271_MAGIC_VALUE, "GS024");
        } else if (v == 1) {
            // If v is 1 then it is an approved hash
            // When handling approved hashes the address of the approver is encoded into r
            currentOwner = address(uint160(uint256(r)));
            // Hashes are automatically approved by the sender of the message or when they have been pre-approved via a separate transaction
            require(msg.sender == currentOwner || approvedHashes[currentOwner][dataHash] != 0, "GS025");
        } else if (v > 30) {
            // If v > 30 then default va (27,28) has been adjusted for eth_sign flow
            // To support eth_sign and similar we adjust v and hash the messageHash with the Ethereum message prefix before applying ecrecover
            currentOwner = ecrecover(keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", dataHash)), v - 4, r, s);
        } else {
            // Default is the ecrecover flow with the provided data hash
            // Use ecrecover with the messageHash for EOA signatures
            currentOwner = ecrecover(dataHash, v, r, s);
        }
        require(currentOwner > lastOwner && owners[currentOwner] != address(0) && currentOwner != SENTINEL_OWNERS, "GS026");
        lastOwner = currentOwner;
    }
}

i really puzzle about contractSignatureLen := mload(add(add(signatures, s), 0x20)),why we need add 0x20.in my opoin,s is direct to contractSignature which incode whth length and elements,so mload(add(add(signatures, s), 0x20)) is just the contractSignatureLen.where do i think worry?

Since signatures is a bytes memory variable, the first thing that is stored at its location is its size and it takes up 32 bytes (0x20 in hexadecimal) so you need to offset the pointer by 32 bytes to get to the signature itself.

ths,i have got it
